# How to associate media with a post?

Tags: posts, media

We are using a WP LMS and use custom posts for the courses.  I would like to have an area in each post where there are course materials.  So on the backend, a section for materials and the front end just simply, media name, description, size.  Feel like I am reinventing the wheel here but if anyone can give me a good first step that would be great.

What I am really looking at here is two things:
1. On front end there be a section (table) with list of associated media/docs.
2. On back end the ability to cross reference the media to page relationship to create dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the users some course material to download, you could simply "Add Media" or "Upload ZIP" into the "Course" content section.

Also if you want only people who start a "Course" to have the course material then you could place the Course material files in the content of the "Unit" post type that you add to the "Course Curriculum" part.

If you just want to have the File name, description and size to be displayed then you would need to add a Custom Field (Meta Boxes) and then modify the single-course template to display these fields.

Comment: It really needs to be its own section so it can be cross-referenced eventually outside of a post/page.